# How to install Atlassian SourceTree in Freya?

Tags: release-freya, software-installation

I need to use  Atlassian SourceTree on my Freya. I am using it for Github and Bitbucket git management. I am not sure its available in `.deb` versions. So I don't know, how to install it.

Can I install SourceTree inside Freya?.

If yes, please guide me to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SourceTree isn't available for Linux (yet?).

There are some alternatives that you can find in the Git official site: https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Comment: Thanks man.  It sounds great.  Let me find an alternative

Answer (score 1):

SourceTree from Atlassian is only available for Windows and Mac and not Linux.
You can express the desire for a linux version here 
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/149631/sourcetree-for-linux

Comment: so it may be released by atlassian. Sofar any tricks to install a windows copy or mac one.

Comment: not mac, maybe windows. you could try to do something with wine. But this will probably be tricky and problematic.

Comment: ok fine. Any alternatives for this Soruce Tree, Which does exactly similar to the same functions